# Using jQuery :gt() with $(this)

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with using `$(this)` and `:gt()` together.

I'm trying to convert this pseudo code into working code:

```
$(this).children().gt(3).show();
```

Will this work? I am trying to show the children of this with an index over 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gt is only a selector as far as I know, not a function, try

```
$(this).children(":gt(3)")
```

or

```
$(this).children().slice(3)
```

Comment: Yep official documentation says it's a selector

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   $(this).children().find(":gt(3)")
```

I'm not sure what gt does but that should be the correct literal translation.